# how to convert format of amount to indonaisa rupiah?

Tags: php, format, currency

we are developing a restaurant system in PHP for indonasia restaurant chain

How i can show the coma-seprated amount in to the **Indonasia Rupiah**

Normally we are showing the amount in our system as like this **9,000,000**

So this amount client want to show as this **9.000.000**

is there any pre-defined method to convert in INDONASIA currency format either i have to use custom function to convert ?

Comment: Try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
$number='9000000';
echo number_format($number, 0, '', '.');
```

Comment: I am using Ipaymu Payment API in PHP from this [https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7508947/SWLfanD1?version=latest#4398a037-041b-41dd-ac62-1a17c61f425f] link. The problem is that my total price **72.59** but Ipaymu convert it to **7.259** So how to set my price that will show 72.59 on Ipaymu payment page.